# Xceed PropertyGrid Collection control customization

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit, propertygrid, xceed

[image: Example of collection]

When I press a collection in a PropertyGrid control I come up with the Collection contro in the image. I don't understand how to remove (1) and (3) and in the list (2) change the name of the type object with custom string, is also possible to insert a progress number before?

```
            <xctk:PropertyGrid x:Name="resinPropertyGrid" 
                           PropertyValueChanged="resinPropertyGrid_PropertyValueChanged" 
                           ShowSearchBox="False" 
                           ShowSortOptions="False" 
                           BorderBrush="#FFABADB3" 
                           Margin="0,3,0,32" 
                           Grid.Row="1">
        </xctk:PropertyGrid>
```

thanks